# How To Select Two classes with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out, how I can select two classes so that when I hover on one of the classes, it does the animation I want. This is what I have tried:

```
.news1 {
    -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
    filter: blur(3px);
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;;

}
.news1:hover .news1msg:hover {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0);
    filter: blur(0);
}
.news1msg {
    -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
    filter: blur(3px);
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;;
}
```

Comment: try putting `,` between class selectors : `.news1:hover, .news1msg:hover`

Comment: `.news1` and `.news1msg` are the same so you can merge these like the hover rules. multiple classes with same rules are `,` seperated. ... and remove the double `;;` and replace with single one!

Comment: What about your HTML structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This selector can match all classes begins with 'news' eg. news1, news1msg

```
[class^="news"] {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0);
    filter: blur(0);
}
```

**Edit:**
In the snippset I suppose you have what you need with your blur.

```css
.news1 {
    background-color:#33aaff;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
    filter: blur(3px);
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;;

}
.news1:hover {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0);
    filter: blur(0);
}
.news1msg {
    color:white;
    font-size:25px;
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;;
}
```

```html
<p class="news1">
  <span class="news1msg">some text</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to apply same css to multiple classes or selectors you can use comma.

```
.class1,
.class2{
     /* some styles */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.news1:hover, .news1msg:hover {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0);
    filter: blur(0);
}
```

Comment: Doing this allows me to hover on one of them and it changes the blur but I am trying to hover on the image and it gets rid of the blur on the text and image

Comment: then need to add img like .news1 img:hover

Answer (score 1):

Use `,` to separate selectors:

```
.news1:hover,
.news1msg:hover {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0);
    filter: blur(0);
}
```

*Just make sore you place `:hover` effect after `.news1msg {` or it will not take effect*

---

If you need to hover on parent and apply blur on child element:

```
 .news1:hover .news1msg {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0);
    filter: blur(0);
 }
```

**You can't apply CSS to parent element if hovering on child**

Comment: Doing this allows me to hover on one of them and it changes the blur but I am trying to hover on the image and it gets rid of the blur on the text and image